# Struts 2 textfield convert apostrophe to "&#39 ;"

Tags: struts2, escaping, textfield, encode, esapi

I am trying to populate name text field with already saved value.

Now the value can contain apostrophe. But text fields is converting **apostrophe** to "`&#39 ;`".

Eg. `sdsd'sds` ==> `sdsd&#39 ;sds`

`escape` property for textfield is not working.

What should I do?

Comment: That's not UTF-8 encoding, it's HTML entities encoding: am I missing something ?

Comment: yes. I am using ESAPI framework to validate and canonicalize the inputs to avoid any XSS. But with this apostrophe is been converted with special symbols.

Comment: This issue got resolved with use of ESAPI.encoder().decodeForHTML() function.

Comment: Answer your question, and add esapi to the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved with use of ESAPI.encoder().decodeForHTML() function. 
The values getting rendered properly after I decode the values before using in s:textfields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because of Encoding feature.
To avoid this and get exactly same as you want, you have to use **`HtmlDecode`** which is available in util package of java.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably **escaping** it server-side.

Don't.

Struts will take care of this.

You only need to specify when you want the opposite (getting the **unescaped** value in the `<s:property />` tag) using the `escapeHtml="false"` property.

---

P.S: there are characters that need a special threatment like the € (euro symbol), but it's another story.