# Struts2 - Escape string in value attribute of textfield tag

Tags: javascript, java, struts2, html-escape-characters

I'm having trouble because of the escape string issue.

The value stated in action is like below:

```
myVo.title = "[M&M]Title";
```

And I want to use it in JSP like below:

```
<s:textfield name="title" id="title" value="%{myVo.title}" />
```

but what I got is this:

[image]

I searched about this problem, but I got no clear answer.

There're some attributes for escape issue like escape/ecapeHtml/escapeXml

but those all are for property tag, not for textfield tag.

How can I solve this problem?

Any comment would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Add `<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
` tags or use charcter code instead of symbol `&`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436841/struts-2-textfield-convert-apostrophe-to-39 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428572/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote?rq=1

Comment: @SumeshTG Thanks for the comment. But the first way does not work. And the second way, I can't because the string data comes from DB.

Comment: If you know the possible symbols you can easily replace them with Unicode corresponding to each character

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable escape like this:

```
<s:textfield name="title" id="title" value="%{myVo.title}" escape="false"/>
```